# select multiple value from drop down list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, drop-down-menu

How to select multiple value from drop down list?, when the value is selected it will no longer be available in the drop down menu.

[[image: Form Select]]

I want can be able to select multiple email addresses at once by pressing the add button where I want to show with a comma separator, so when we choose an email address through the drop down list it will automatically be displayed in the input field 'To' such as: neymar@gmail.com, ronaldo@gmail.com, messi@gmail.com then the user can also delete the last email in the input by pressing the delete button,

Comment: Update you question with specific problem. dont use **Can I use the code below and modify it or is there another easier way to do this?** Try it by yourself.

Comment: Why not to simply use <select multiple>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must concat value of `selectBox` to **previous value** and replace it to your inputBox.

```js
     var prv_val,f_val;
        $('#test').change(function() {
          var new_val = $(this).val();
          if(new_val != ""){
            prv_val = $('#target_input').val();
            if(prv_val != ""){
              f_val = prv_val + "," + new_val;
            }
            else {
              f_val = new_val;
            }
            $('#target_input').val(f_val);
          }
        });
```

```css
#target_input {
     display: block;
      height: 30px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      width : 100%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <select id='test'>
         <option value=""></option>
          <option value="one@gamil.com">one@gamil.com</option>
          <option value="two@gamil.com">two@gamil.com</option>
          <option value="three@gamil.com">three@gamil.com</option>
        </select>

        <input value="" id='target_input'>
```

Comment: how to remove it if user mistaken in choosing selectbox?

Comment: you should codding on click event on buttons

Answer (score 0):

For multiple selection create a list box if you are using asp.net control.

If you are using HTML add multiple attribute.

Follow this link

https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_select_multiple.asp

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) button to select multiple options. 
Use multiple attribute inside your select tag.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <select name="cars" multiple>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```